# File Handling : unusual error reading file

Tags: c, file, encryption, openssl, file-handling

The output of the program is this :

Although correct contents

(for now only when trying to decrypt producing wrong result)

but why this error ??

```
udit@udit-Dabba /opt/lampp/htdocs $ ./a.out
Error reading password from BIO
Error getting password
Salted__�Yq\��v��u�&2�t���-�
```

The code for program is this -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void crypto(uint8_t *key, uint32_t keylen, uint8_t *data, uint32_t datalen);

int main () {

    uint8_t icv[10]="uditgupta";

    uint8_t ekey[14]="1234567891011";

    uint8_t *key=ekey;

    uint8_t *data=icv;

    crypto(ekey,13,icv,9);


    return 0;

    }


  void crypto(uint8_t *key, uint32_t keylen,uint8_t *data, uint32_t datalen)
  {

  int ch,i;
  uint8_t mydata[100],modata[100];
  uint8_t *p=mydata;


  FILE *fp,*fq,*fr;

  fp=fopen("key","w");
  fputs(key,fp);
  fq=fopen("file.txt","w");
  fputs(data,fq);

  memset(data,0,sizeof(data));

  system("sudo openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt
 -out file.enc -pass file:key");

 fr=fopen("file.enc","r");

 memset(mydata,0,sizeof(mydata));

 i=0;

 while( (ch=fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {
            mydata[i]=ch;
            i++;
 }

 i=0;

 puts(p);

 }
```

I think i need to change the read/write mode of file but not sure...Please guide me what an I doing wrong ???

Comment: It seems the openssl is causing this problem....

Comment: @acme no its working fine when used alone in another file...its for sure some reading mode problem as i have understood it.

Comment: @acme if it seems an openssl problem to you then  please suggest me something...i am new to this openssl thing.

Comment: Try either flushing or closing `fq` and `fp` before the `system` call

Comment: @udit gupta - If you really think that might be the problem, then try opening the file in binary mode `fopen("filename", "rb");`.... but if its a normal text i don't think you need to go into this mess for your problem. Try to update the OpenSSL ... and see if it works..

Comment: you have not mentioned what does 'key' & 'data' contain. If your input to fputs is not newline-terminated it may get buffered and never get written to file!                                            Do an fflush(fp) before you call system()

Comment: You're leaking memory and file descriptors by not closing your files.  Make sure to call `fclose` on each file after you're done with it.  Secondly, you have a potential buffer overflow: what happens if `file.enc` contains more than 100 bytes?

Comment: @Dmitri yes....you are right error removed but now contents of encrpted file are correct but after decryption wrong results are produced.but i think that must be a problem of openssl and i need to create a new thread for that.The problem for this thread is solved. But will you suggest me what should i do now there is no answer to this thread so i can not accept any answer..then how should i close this thread. or i have to delete the post.

Comment: @Acme how to upgrade openssl please suggest me...i am using ubuntu and tried sudo apt-get update/upgrade but thats not the right command for updating openssl packege.

Comment: What's your openssl version? I have 0.9.8g and it works for me. Try it in the shell before doing in a program. Why are you using sudo?

Comment: @UditGupta I restated the comment in an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either flushing or closing `fq` and `fp` before the call to `system`.  The problem is probably that the data you have just written to the files has not been flushed to disk yet when the openssl command is run.

Answer (score 0):

*how to upgrade openssl*

Upgrade to latest Platform.

[OpenSSL Tarballs](http://www.openssl.org/source/)

For more read [How to update OpenSSL using Putty and yum command](https://serverfault.com/questions/143582/how-to-update-openssl-using-putty-and-yum-command)